# Parsing error : Identifier 'reducer' has already been declared in store.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, nodemon

**store.js**

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, compose, applyMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { productListReducer } from './reducers/productReducers';
import reducer from './reducers';


const initialState= {};
const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
})
const composeEnhancer =window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

export default store;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Routes,Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen';

function App() {

  const openMenu =() => {
    document.querySelector(".sidebar").classList.add ('open');
  }
  const closeMenu = () => {
    document.querySelector(".sidebar").classList.remove('open');
  }
  return (
<BrowserRouter>
    <div className="grid-container">
      <header className="header">
        <div className="brand">
          <button onClick={openMenu}>
            &#9776;
          </button>
          <Link to="/" >LETS SHOP 4U</Link>
        </div>
        <div className="header-links">
          <a href="cart.html">Cart</a>
          <a href="signin.html">Sign In</a>
        </div>
      </header>
      <aside className="sidebar">
        <h3>Shopping Categories</h3>
        <button className="sidebar-close-button" onClick={closeMenu}>x</button>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Vegetables</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Fruits</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Grains</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Meat</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Oil</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Tuber</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Cereals</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Spices</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Others</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </aside>
      <main className="main">
        <div className="content">
          <Routes>
          <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen/> } ></Route>
          <Route path="/" exact={true}element={<HomeScreen/>} />
          <Route path="/" render={(props) => <HomeScreen {...props} />} ></Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer className="footer">
        All right reserved.
      </footer>
       </div>
       </BrowserRouter>
      );
      }
  export default App;
```

**package.json**

```
  "name": "frontend",
 ,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "components": "^0.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.5",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "styled": "^1.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}


  "name": "new-project-1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --watch backend --exec babel-node backend/server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/node": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9"
  }
}
```

i am learning from a video tutorial and i did everything the video says and so far i have been successful until i run into this problem.

i tried changing the 'createstore' to configureStore even though the video did not use the configurestore
but still i cant solve this problem.

Comment: The error states precisely what, and where, the error is.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining two variables with the name `reducer` there:

```
import reducer from './reducers';
```

and

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
})
```

You cannot have two different variables with the same name. You need to give one of them another name.

Comment: How do I do this exactly

Comment: Replace one of the two occurrences of the word `reducer` with another word.

Comment: And maybe evaluate why you have that `reducer` import there in the first place, because you don't seem to be using that anywhere. Maybe you can just delete that line.

Comment: Also, just looking at this again: You are right that you should be using `@reduxjs/toolkit` nowadays, but you should not really be using any of `createStore, combineReducers, compose, applyMiddleware` or `thunk` directly with RTK. All of these have essenitally been incorporated/replaced with `configureStore`, back in 2019. You might still be writing a very outdated style of Redux despite importing stuff from the new package. Have you tried following the [official Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts)?